# Why does Objective-C allow a successful call to null objects?

Tags: objective-c, nullpointerexception, null

What is the use of this ( besides the non crash part ) ?
I want to know in terms of thinking process behind such design.

Comment: That non-crash part is probably the biggest factor here.

Comment: I would also refer you to [Working with Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1) section of the _Programming with Objective-C_ guide (specifically, the [Working with nil](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW22) section).

Comment: This is a valid question. It is *not* opinion-based, there was a reason for a decision, and the asker wants to know it. It's quite objective.

Answer (score 5):

It's a design choice. And in Objective-C terminology, one "sends messages" to objects, instead of "calling methods". So you could say sending a message to an object that doesn't exist has simply no effect. If you address a real letter to a person that doesn't exist, no one will receive it, no one will respond or do anything.

Comment: but didn't it makes the debugging difficult ?

Comment: If you're used to the way other languages handle this, maybe. But really, no. You just have to anticipate the possibility and use it to your advantage.

Comment: It's a trade off between convenience and safety I guess.

Comment: No, it's not making debug difficult, you can add a breakpoint and see that 'the object' is nil. It's just a possibility you need to take into account, and most of the time this is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from a Java background, one of the thing I found hard to "make mine", was the total absence of the famous `java.lang.NullPointerException` related to method invocation.

Once you get into it, you will find it is a total different approach and not a bad one also: you send a message, and if someone is not responding the program is not crashing.

This lead to enforce (in my opinion of course) to think about returning value, rather than to worry about  something existing.